# Return meaningful error from repo?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is a good practice to return error to a controller. Error could be like invalid ID (not found from db) or updating data to DB has failed. Should I use array to return error?

Assume we have this in the controller:

```
public function enableOrDisableStatus($id)
{

  $this->status->setStatusEnable($id)) {
        // Update
    } else {
       // Throw Error
    }

 }
```

In the repo:

```
public function setStatusEnable($id)
{

    $status = $this->getStatusById($id);

    if (is_null($status))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $status->enabled = 1;
    return $status->save();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with throwing an exception?

Comment: Just throw an appropriate exception from your Repository.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Please provide answer.